# VBA connect to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, vba, wamp

I try to connect my Excel Spreadsheet to my MySQL DB hosted locally for the moment. I'm using WAMPSERVER.

Here is my VBA code :

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=test;" & _
        "USER=root;" & _
        "PASSWORD=;" & _
        "Option=3"
End Sub
```

I created my db "test" on through phpMyadmin... I have an error when I run the code.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: ok, what is the error?

Comment: @mehow It seems to be an Execution error '-2147467259 (80004005)', automation error and unspecified error

Comment: have you tried using UID and PWD instead of USER and PASSWORD ? + check your mysql version maybe its older than 5.1 so you may need to change your driver version to ie. 3.51 

or find a matching String [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Comment: @mehow I changed USER and PASSWORD as UID and PWD and I got the same error... I also installed an older driver version 3.51 and it is not working neither...

Comment: does debugger point at the string when its throwing the error?

Comment: What are you on 64 or 32 bit? Which version of MySQL 64 or 32? You might like to check http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql. For me ( 64 / 64 ) this works `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;Option=3;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to a wrong references defined. In the VBE, I had to click on Tools>References and check the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library", and only this one.

The macro is properly running now under WAMP (with default parameters Username = root and Pwd = "") on Windows 7 with the following code :

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=excel;" & _
        "USER=root;" & _
        "PASSWORD=;" & _
        "Option=3"
End Sub
```